# Keras warning: Epoch comprised more than `samples_per_epoch` samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have about 6200 training images and I  want to use the `flow(X, y)` method of the `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` class to augment the small dataset in the following way:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X_train , y_train)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_val , y_val)

history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=1920,
        nb_epoch=10,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        nb_val_samples=800)
```

where `X_train` / `y_train` contain about 6000 training images and labels and `X_val` / `y_val` the validation data and model is an augmented VGG16 model.

The documentation says

> flow(X, y): Takes numpy data & label arrays, and generates batches of augmented/normalized data. Yields batches indefinitely, in an infinite loop.

For a training setup with 10 epochs, 1920 samples per epoch and a batch_size of 32 I got the following training trace:

```
1920/1920 [==============================] - 3525s - loss: 3.9101 - val_loss: 0.0269
Epoch 2/10
1920/1920 [==============================] - 3609s - loss: 1.0245 - val_loss: 0.0229
Epoch 3/10
1920/1920 [==============================] - 3201s - loss: 0.7620 - val_loss: 0.0161
Epoch 4/10
1916/1920 [============================>.] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5978 C:\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:1537: UserWarning: Epoch comprised more than `samples_per_epoch` samples, which might affect learning results. Set `samples_per_epoch` correctly to avoid this warning.
  warnings.warn('Epoch comprised more than
```

Why didnt the generator generate infinite batches as the documentation says?

Comment: Please add code that shows how you define your model and image data generator.

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: Why is samples_per_epoch equal to 1920 when you have 6000 training images?

Comment: If I set it to 6200, wouldn't the "Epoch comprised more than `samples_per_epoch` samples" occur in the 2nd epoch?

Comment: "Epoch" usually means exposing a learning algorithm to the entire set of training data. So `samples_per_epoch` is usually equal to the number of training images.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. But in what way is the dataset augmented if I use the whole trainingset each epoch?

Comment: It is being augmented "on the fly", the specified transformations are applied each time the image generator yields an image during all epochs.

Comment: But doesnt that mean I can set  samples_per_epoch to a larger value then the length of my initial dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically there is a small mistake in a `KerasImageGenerator` class implementation. What is nice - that beside this annoying warning nothing wrong happens. So to clarrify:

1. Both `flow`and `flow_from_directory` actually yields samples in an infinite loop. You could easly check that by testing the following code (warning - it will freeze your `Python`):

   ```
   for x, y in train_generator:
       x = None
   ```
2. The warning which you mentioned is rasied in a `fit_generator` method. It basically checks if the number of samples processed in one epoch is lesser or equal to `samples_per_epoch`. In your case - where `samples_per_epoch` is divisible by a `batch_size` - if implementation of Keras would be correct - this warning should be never raised... but..
3. .. yeah, so why this warning was raised? It's a little bit tricky. If you went deeper into implementation of a generator you would notice that generator is getting batches in a following manner : if you have let's say - 10 examples and `batch_size = 3` then:

   - it will first shuffle the order of this 10 examples,
   - then it would take 3 first of shuffled examples, then next three and so on,
   - after the 3rd batch - when there is only 1 example left - it will return a batch.. with only one sample.

   Don't ask me why - this is the way how generator is implemented. Good thing is that it barely affects the training process.

So - to sum up - you could either ignore this warning or you could make the number of samples you pass to a generator divisible by a `batch_size`. I know that it's cumbersome and I hope it will be fixed in a next release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mention "flow_from_directory actually yields samples in an infinite loop". Does everything you say apply to the flow-method as well? Because thats the one I am using.

Comment: Yes. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. If I use the setup above and feed the complete training set to the network each epoch (samples_per_epoch = number_of_training_samples) - may I assume, that the generator produces a slightly different dataset each epoch and thus increases variance?